# AngularFire email authentication error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have the following code that calls my firebase factory. I have it working if the user enters a valid username and password, but when I have a wrong username and password I get an error 400.

Here is the call on my factory to the firebase

```
firebaseObj.loginUser = function(username,password){
    return auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password);
};
```

here is my controller call to the factory

```
loc.doLogin = function(){
   firebaseFactory.loginUser(loc.userinfo.email,loc.userinfo.password).then(function(resp){
      console.log(resp.uid);
   }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
};
```

Any idea why if I enter a valid username and password it work and if I enter a wrong info I get an error 400?

https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=XXXXXXXXXXX 400 ()

Answer (score 0):

you must enable the authentication with email in your dashabord firebase

go to your firebase console  login $ Auth

Comment: I do have that enabled on my console. I only get that 400 error when I enter an invalid username and password, I also get the response back saying invalid authentication.

Comment: can you show me your code ? when you recive 400 , use .catch(function(err)) to hundle error

Comment: It is normal for the backend to return a 400 when a sign in attempt does not succeed no matter what the reason is. You cannot change that behavior.